# About a representation on cardinals

Tags: set-theory

If k is a limit cardinal, necessarly one have that  $ ZFC ^  {R_{K}}  $ ?

And, if k is only ordinal, does it have any sense?

Answer (score 2):

If $\kappa$ is not a strong limit cardinal, then the answer is clearly not. Because in that case there is some $\alpha<\kappa$ such that $R_\alpha\geq\kappa$, in which case $R_\kappa\models R_\alpha\text{ cannot be put in bijection with an ordinal}$.

If $\kappa$ is a strong limit cardinal, but not a fixed point of the $\beth$ function then $\kappa=\beth_\alpha$ and $\alpha<\kappa$. In that case we have a definable function whose domain is $\alpha$, but its range is unbounded in the ordinals of $R_\kappa$. So replacement fails.

If $\kappa$ is not a limit cardinal (ordinal or otherwise), then $R_\kappa$ thinks that there is a maximal cardinal, so it doesn't satisfy $\sf ZFC$.

More specifically if $\sf ZFC$ can prove $\kappa$ with a certain property exists, then it doesn't prove that $R_\kappa$ *necessarily* satisfies $\sf ZFC$. This is true for limit ordinals, cardinals, limit cardinals, strong limit cardinals, and so on. If $\sf ZFC$ can prove it exists, it can't prove that $R_\kappa$ is a model of $\sf ZFC$.

Comment: The general statement in your last paragraph is not quite true.  Let $\varphi(\kappa)$ say "$\kappa$ is the least inaccessible cardinal if it exists, and 0 otherwise."  Then $\mathsf{ZFC} \vdash \exists \kappa\,\varphi(\kappa)$, but (assuming the consistency of inaccessibles) $\mathsf{ZFC} \not\vdash \exists \kappa \,(\varphi(\kappa) \wedge R_\kappa \not\vDash \mathsf{ZFC})$.

Comment: We need to coin a term for properties which avoid this smartassery. I'll fix this later, thanks :-)

Comment: I think it works for $\Sigma_2$ statements.  Alternatively, you could weaken the conclusion to "it _can't_ prove that $R_\kappa$ _does_ have to be a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$."